# Device disconnection(Time out) logic in pyspark stream

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying if kafka doesn't receive any message for 45 seconds query running should be stopped(query.stop()), In middle of that 45 seconds if new message received start time needs to be reset again. As per my below code once message received after 45 minutes it stopped, but start time never getting reset or query is not executing that every 15 minutes once it is entered into if condition.

```
   def func(batch_df, batch_id):
        # query = explode_df.writeStream.format("console").queryName("worst").trigger(processingTime= "15 second").outputMode("append").foreachBatch(func).start()
        global start_time
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        message=batch_df.groupBy().agg(count("*")).collect()[0][0]
        if (message != 0):
            batch_df.show()
            while True:
             current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
             elapsed_time = (current_time - start_time).total_seconds()

             if elapsed_time >= 45:
              print("closing")
              print(datetime.datetime.now)
              query.stop()
              break
                
                
        
    query = explode_df.writeStream.format("console").trigger(processingTime= "15 second").outputMode("append").foreachBatch(func).start()
```

want to stop the query if message is not received for 45 seconds meantime if new message receives start time needs to reset and start count 45 sec